# Angular 8 app freezes on live-reload and locks up browser tab

Tags: angular, angular-cli, livereload

When using Angular CLI to develop, I will be able to go a few hours without any issue, but at seemingly random times, the browser locks up with no errors, and the tab indicates that the app is still loading. I'm still able to use the devtools, but the tab refuses to close, so I eventually have to force quit Chrome.

I do have styles inside the app-root tags:

```
    <app-root>
      <style>
        .logo-wrapper svg {
          opacity: 1 !important;
        }

        .logo-wrapper {
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) !important;
        }
      </style>
    </app-root>
```

The logo dissappears, as it should, so I know Angular has bootstrapped itself at this point.

The first time it occurred was after upgrading to Angular 8 and adding loading screen styles to index.html

It's not a lot of details, but I have searched extensively for a solution without finding one or finding anyone that has had a similar issue.

```
import 'hammerjs'; // Required for @angular/material gestures

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from '@app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

bootstrap().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

CLI version info:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.15.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: undefined
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          8.3.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.803.4 (cli-only)
```

Angular dependency info:

```
 "@angular/animations": "^8.2.6",
 "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.0",
 "@angular/common": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/compiler": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/core": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
 "@angular/forms": "^8.2.6",
 "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.4",
 "@angular/router": "8.2.6",
 "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.6"

dev-deps: 
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.4",
 "@angular/cli": "8.3.4",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.6",
```

Comment: Why are you adding an style tag to the app-root?, it must be empty before the app starts, move it to a css file or out of the app-root

Comment: Start commenting out code, components, modules. Look for memory leaks and recursion bugs where you may have accidentally be caught in a loop. With little details, this is where I would start.

Comment: app-root doesn't have to be empty. It just will get erased as soon as the app loads, as the OP stated.

Comment: @shadowfox476 I'll start by commenting out the loading screen code. The CPU does seem to run hot when this occurs, so a recursion bug may be the culprit. The problem is that it's not consistent on when it occurs, so I am unable to reproduce it. It just occurs at random intervals as I work. Are there any tools to debug the angular bootstrap process?

Comment: In your main.ts file, when your app is bootstraped, do you have a catch statement? bootstrapModule.then(...).catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: Yes, there is a catch. I've updated my question with my main.ts file's code

Comment: Any luck with the problem?

Comment: No, the problem has not been occurring anymore, and it only affects me and not the rest of my team. So, I think it was an issue with my local copy of the Angular CLI